# What template has the least "wasted" space for headings, sections, etc

Tags: spacing, sectioning, templates

Does anyone have suggestions for a document template that doesn't look terrible but is the most economical with regard to space used up for headings, sections, titles, and so forth?  The AMS article template is quite good, but I'd like to know if there's one out there that's even better.

(More to the point:  if I have a strict page/margin/font/spacing limit for something, what package/template is the best for maximizing the amount of content I can still include, while not looking completely ridiculous?)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

The `titlesec` package allows you to manipulate some of these parameters. For example, the following MWE makes the size of titles and section headings much smaller by using `tiny` (other options are `big`, which is the default value, `medium`, and `small`). `compact` reduces the spacing between section headings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tiny,compact]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

\section{Example Example}

\section{Example Example Example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see the `titlesec` [documentation](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) for more on what you can do with the package.